# ODBC Data Source Administrator - missing tcp/ip for installed driver

Tags: db2, odbc

When I open the ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit) to configure it for DB2 connections, I try to add a System DSN, and then add a DB2 database alias. The issue is that when adding the alias, the CLI/ODBC Settings don't show a TCP/IP tab so that I can enter in my db connection info. The only tabs listed are Data Source and Advanced Settings.

This is the 32-bit version of the driver. The 64-bit version has the TCP/IP tab and I configure it fine, but I need to be able to connect to a 32 bit instance.

How can I resolve this?

Here's what it looks like with the missing tabs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54j5Y.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set those properties in the Advanced settings:

Add entries for the properties `Hostname` (use the ip address or hostname), `Port` (usually its 50000 for DB2) and that should be enough. Maybe you also need to set Property `Protocol`.

Note: I have never seen a tab to configure the TCP-IP Settings with the DB2 driver. Are you sure you want to use the DB2 driver and not the `iSeries Access ODBC Driver`? I think this has tabs to define the server connection properties.

Comment: Thanks, my db2 apps are running now.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue (not seeing the "TCP/IP" tab) while adding a DSN for the DB2 instance (v10.5) on our server. I added the following properties in the "Advanced Settings" tab, as suggested ;

Hostname: [ip address or hostname of the server]

Port: 50000

Database: [DB2 database I need to connect to]

After specifying the User ID & Password on the "Data Source" tab, the connection was successful and now I am able to work on the DB2 database using MS Access (Win 7, Office 2010).

Thank you!!!